# Did two Great Danes really fight a tiger?

Tags: film-techniques, swiss-family-robinson

We were just watching the 1960 Swiss Family Robinson movie and shortly after they land on their island there is a scene where two Great Danes appear to actually attack a Bengal Tiger.

[image: Tiger]

There is a bad quality video on YouTube for those interested, but I'm not going to link it.

How was this scene filmed?  I don't know the endangered status of the tiger in the 60's but did they really just let two Great Danes attack a Tiger?

Answer (score 1):

The tiger was real, but the attack was 'acted out' by the animals. The animals were trained by trainers "and went over attitudes or gestures that the animals should play." ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swiss_Family_Robinson_(1960_film)#Cast)) Everthing is essentially real, but the attack itself was an act.